# Display binary image in grid with popup

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datagrid

I have an asp.net datagrid on my page. This grid will have three column. Id, date and photo.

The photo column, is an actual column on the table VARBINARY(MAX).

When the user clicks on the photo (which will be either a text or an icon) I want to open a jquery modal with the photo in its full size. The user than can right click and save if he want.

I've never done this before. Tried to search on the net but I only find examples on displaying the image into the column, which is not what I want.

Comment: check this : http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-GridView-Row-details-inside-jQuery-Dialog-Modal-Popup-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Thanks! That kind lead me to the way of showing the dialog. But Now, how do I display the image on the dialog? If I do display the image on the column itself, can I recreate it bigger in the dialog?

Comment: have a look at my answer. don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below code sample to display small image in grid and displaying it large by clicking on it.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvData" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img src='<%# "data:image/gif;base64," + Eval("Data")  %>' onclick="DisplayImage(this)" height="10" width="10" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<%--Popup dialog to display large image--%>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
    <img height="100" width="100" id="imgLargeImage" />
</div>
```

**Note:** here my image type is `gif` so update it as per your image type.

**JavaScript to display image in popup :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisplayImage(ctrl) {

        document.getElementById('imgLargeImage').src = ctrl.src;

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "View Details",
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            modal: true
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. For future references, in my case I did with small differences. I used an http handler to fetch the bytes of the image. These two examples guided me: 
http://bit.ly/1pRq5vc and http://bit.ly/1ecyynE

Comment: thats good thing. i supposed to suggest the same but i thought it would be your next question :)